# Function pointers in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I am creating C++/CLI application in which I have using 3rd party tools API. One of the API has declaration in help documents as as

```
 Error GetDrawingComponents(Drawing oDrawing,DrawingComponentVisit compVisit,DrawingComponentFilter compFilter)

Error (*DrawingComponentVisit) (DrwSolid solid,Error status) 

Error (*DrawingComponentFilter) (DrwSolid solid,Error status,Filter filStatus)
```

Now I have used this API in my application in my .CPP I have used it like below-

```
  Error chkError =  GetDrawingComponents(Drawing oDrawing,(DrawingComponentVisit)oClsObj::VisitDrawingComponents,(DrawingComponentFilter)oClsObj::FilterDrawingComponents);
```

CPP file also contains defination of VisitDrawingComponents and FilterDrawingComponents. They are declared in .h file as following -

```
Error VisitDrawingComponents(DrwSolid solid,Error status); 
Error FilterDrawingComponents(DrwSolid solid,Error status,Filter filStatus);
```

So now using it above way I am getting typecast error

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'DrawingComponentVisit'
```

I Can use this API the same way if I have unmanaged C++ application. Please let me know waht changes I will need to do to make this work in C++/CLI application?

Comment: You should *never* use a cast to try to whack a function pointer into the right shape.  Remove it and you'll get a better error message about the mismatch.  Some odds that you haven't told the compiler that these are unmanaged functions, use #pragma un/managed around the #include.

Comment: Ok , Now I have removed type cast and modified call as Error chkError = GetDrawingComponents(Drawing oDrawing,&oClsObj::VisitDrawingComponents,&oClsObj::FilterDrawingComponents); Now I am getting another error message as -          Error 1 error C3374: can't take address of oClsObj::VisitDrawingComponentsunless creating delegate instance

Comment: That looks better.  Still don't know what oClsObj might be, it doesn't appear anywhere in your snippets.  You'll indeed need a delegate if you want native code to call a managed method.